# How to get iPhone IP address using 4g network?

Tags: ios, swift

How to get IP address using 4g network? I am trying this code not but I am not receiving the actual IP address. The IP address from https://api.ipify.org/ is not the same as this code.

How to get correct IP address?

```swift
func getIPAddress() -> String {
    var address: String?
    var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil
    if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
        var ptr = ifaddr
        while ptr != nil {
            defer { ptr = ptr?.pointee.ifa_next }

            guard let interface = ptr?.pointee else { return "" }
            let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
            if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                // wifi = ["en0"]
                // wired = ["en2", "en3", "en4"]
                // cellular = ["pdp_ip0","pdp_ip1","pdp_ip2","pdp_ip3"]

                let name: String = String(cString: (interface.ifa_name))
                if  name == "en0" || name == "en2" || name == "en3" || name == "en4" || name == "pdp_ip0" || name == "pdp_ip1" || name == "pdp_ip2" || name == "pdp_ip3" {
                    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                    getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t((interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len)), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                    address = String(cString: hostname)
                }
            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    }
    return address ?? ""
}
```

Comment: I think `ipify` works fine, just parse the response followed by their public API. However, every time you switch on/off 4G, the IP address will change.

Comment: Your carrier is probably using CGNAT. The address that your phone has and the address that a web site your phone connects to will be different.